# Comparing dates to see if a date is expired

Tags: excel, vba, date, comparison

I am trying to compare a column filled with dates with the current date. If a date in the column is smaller than current date then i paint the whole row in red. My code is below:

```
   With wb8.Sheets(1)
      For Each rCell In .Range(.Cells(2, "W"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp))
         If IsDate(rCell) Then
            If Format(rCell, "dd.mm.yyyy") < Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") Then
            rCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End If
         End If
      Next rCell
   End With
```

Now this code works but the results are not accurate as it is seen in the image below

[image]

I suspect that the comparison is not working properly but i am not that skilled in VBA so can't find the problem. Could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/1900-and-1904-date-system):

> When you enter a date, the date is converted into a serial number that
> represents the number of elapsed days starting with 1 for January 1,
> 1900. For example, if you enter July 5, 1998, Excel converts the date to the serial number 35981.

This means that you can simply compare the serial numbers as integers.

```
If rCell.Value < Date Then
  rCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End If
```

Comment: Hello there EylM. I tried your solution but it returned no red rows. So then i created a new variable and stored the current date in there and made the comparison with that variable instead and then it worked perfectly good!